# How to get the images of a facebook album using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the links of Facebook photos in albums posted from a page that I am managing. I tried to use facebook graph API. I could get the names and ids of albums via "{page_id}/albums/" . Then I tried to use the album id/?fields=photos{link} to get the link. But here it will provide facebook link (eg:https://www.facebook.com/page_name/photos/a.193909724216/193907241065159/?type=3)
But I want to show this images on a page. So I want the real image path. (eg:https://scontent.fcmb1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/38801583_193907078972459378765588463616_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=6bdfdfc0cc225a1f035295bb2e2a8&oe=5BF8A013).

Can I get them using Facebook graph API?

Comment: you should never store real image paths, facebook does not guarantee that they will stay the same. either store the photo itself (probably better) or the photo id only.

Comment: I am not going to store. I am going to use facebook api to fetch the images when the site loads

Comment: if you do that for every user who hits your page, you will most likely hit facebooks api limits...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo - you probably want the `images` field.